# Logistic regression prediction changed after executed couple of time

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, pandas, probability

I noticed that after each time I execute the following lines of code, my results are different. Any idea why?
I think  that the main issue here is this line of code
But I dont understand why?

test_data['prediction']=sentiment_model.predict_proba(test_matrix)[:,0]

What is the best way to add new column with .predict_prob()?

```
test_data['prediction'] = sentiment_model.predict_proba(test_matrix)[:,0]
test_data['prediction_label'] = sentiment_model.predict(test_matrix) 
test_data['prediction'] = test_data['prediction'].apply(lambda x: round(x,2)) 
test_data.sort_values(by='prediction', ascending=False, inplace=True) 
test_data[test_data['name'] == 'Britax Decathlon Convertible Car Seat, Tiffany']
test_data.head()
```

Comment: there may be randomness at some point along the process e.g. random initialization of  weights and/or biases, dataset shuffling, ...

Comment: You need to present more of the algorithm. E.g. the setup of the model, not just getting the model results.

Answer (score 2):

There is some randomness in the results from selecting/shuffling data that is used in the model.

If you don't want that, you could set a fixed random_state (seed) in your model.

Comment: Can you please go into details, the answer is a liitle bit unclear,                                    How can i avoid it? Why it's happening ?

Comment: Sorry but it's not correct I use Jupyter and I execute this lines of code, So it's not an issue of spliiting the datqa, moreever i split the data with fix values for each item

Answer (score 1):

My guess - the order of labels entered as training set is different.
From the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.predict_proba) -

The returned estimates for all classes are ordered by the label of classes.

So make sure you know which class prediction probability your slicing when using the [:, 0] in the first row.